# How does iterate_structure work in scipy?

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, shared-objects, mathematical-morphology

I have been exploring morphological image processing techniques and have been using scipy for performing those techniques. Currently migrating some of these methods to JS.

Recently, I came across this method `iterate_structure` in scipy, which describes "Iterate a structure by dilating it with itself."

- It is difficult to understand the output it returns. Can someone explain the working of it?
- And while going through the source code of the method. It uses a method through the ".so" file called "_nd_image", Is it possible to know the method description?
- Are there any scipy like packages for browser javascript?

`iterate_structure` documentation

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.iterate_structure.html

usage of method from .so files in source code,

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/3f017716532001349ccddb05498408d711bacdde/scipy/ndimage/morphology.py#L253

Thanks in advance!

Have a great day!

Comment: Have you actually used this, or is this some sort 'do a full translation' project.?  The .so is compiled code, possibly a third party library, or custom interface to such.

Comment: @hpaulj, Yes!, your rite, I'm doing a translation of a python project to javascript. Currently, I have kinda understood the working of the `iterate_structure` but it would have been easier if the function description of the .so method were mentioned.

Comment: Going up the github file structure I find `scipy/scipy/ndimage/src/nd_image.c`, the source code for the `_nd_image.so`.  Also in the docs I find a more direct call to this `binary_erosion` with docs, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.binary_erosion.html#scipy.ndimage.binary_erosion

Comment: Ahh, thanks @hpaulj for the .so file location!, Will try to figure its implementation if possible